# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41) flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase

My project was working just fine yesterday, I went to sleep then woke up next thing I see is a bunch of errors, I got sick of it so I just created a new project and copied the necessary stuff, now I'm facing a new error:

`E/flutter (11112): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null) E/flutter (11112): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7) E/flutter (11112): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter (11112): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25) E/flutter (11112): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter (11112): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31) E/flutter (11112): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter (11112): #3      main (package:untitled7/main.dart:29:3) E/flutter (11112): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter (11112):`

I made sure that I got everything set up, from yaml to build, but it still gives that error up there, here's my main:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  await UserSettings.init();
  print('${UserSettings.status}');
  String initialRoute = UserSettings.status ? FlashScreen.id : '/';
  runApp(Main(initialRoute: initialRoute));
}
```

I'd like to see any help :D

Updated packages, made sure Json is there updated, and made sure build is set up